# Android TextService that interfaces between InputMethod and Application

Tags: android, android-service

After reading some of the TextServicesManager documentation (android.view.textservice.TextServicesManager), it seems like I am able to create a new Text Service that can handle information passed from the Input method to the Application (but not the Spell Checker). According to the TextServicesManager documentation... "The spell checker session is one of the text services". Does this mean that there are other types of text service?

The TextServicesManager is obviously a final class that can't be extended. That manager only has one newSpellCheckerSession () method which returns a Spell Checker Session... clearly I would be unable to create a new Text Service (session) completely unrelated to a spell checker. I feel like the documentation may be misleading me on this manager...

I feel a medium between input method and application/service sending away content to a server would be a useful tool for a number of reasons.

Can someone please clarify if this is possible with text services manager and if not, should I be looking in a different direction?

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen these link. They explain how to create a Spell checkers for Android.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/spell-checker-framework.html

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/08/creating-your-own-spelling-checker.html